# How can keep the log as it is without any additional information from syslog?

Tags: rsyslog

I have server with RHEL 6 and rsyslog-5.8 and Apache/2.2.23, I sent the access and error logs to syslog server but the syslog adds information in logs such as date and hostname:

ex:

**Jun  5 14:17:28 (hostname) httpd[4584]:** [error] [client XXXX] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/file

How can keep the log as it is without any additional information from syslog?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're doing ? Are you sending your httpd logs to a centralised syslog server on your network or are you just sending them to the syslog on the local machine ?

Comment: I have 2 web servers and I want to write the access and error log in one place

Answer (score 2):

Don't log to syslog.

```
ErrorLog /my/own/log
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I have 2 web servers and I want to write the access and error log in one place and I have other applications read from the logs to generate many reports and the change in the form of logs make many of the problems.

Comment: You will have to do something different, then. For instance use different log analysis tools. And the first step will be don't log to syslog.